# How I can get "local.oplog.rs" count with mongodb\driver php

Tags: php, mongodb

## When I type in mongo-cli:

```
#use local
#db.oplog.rs.stats()
```

I need get the var "count" from this output

[image]

I'm trying smth like this, but it's return NULL

```
 $mongo_connection = MongoDB\Driver\Manager() ;
 $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(["count" => 1]) ;
 $res = $mongo_connection->executeQuery("local.oplog.rs", $query) ; 
 var_dump($res); ------>> Null
```

Comment: Try [executeCommand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executecommand.php#example-1251)

Comment: It's a db with collection name. Unfortunately command ​does not fit. I gues that i need smth like ->executeQuery(dbname.dbcollectionname, 'Query'). But I still not understand howI can use this...

Comment: Example #3 on that page is running `count` on a collection.

Comment: I'm using new mongodb php driver. In the legacy version it looked like this:$sdb = $mng->selectDB('local') ;
       $mongo_collection = $sdb->oplog.rs ;
       $oplog_rs_count = $mongo_collection->count() ;